# Why is Cache.asMap() not consistent with Cache.size()?

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, guava

In the Guava Library, I am confused about why [`Cache.asMap()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#asMap%28%29) is not consistent with [`Cache.size()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#size%28%29), unless [`Cache.cleanUp()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#cleanUp%28%29) is called.

```
Cache<Object, Object> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
           .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .build();
cache.get(...);
...
//After some seconds, all entries are expired.
//cache.asMap() is EMPTY Map, but cache.size() != 0
```

So my question: Is it bug that `Cache.asMap()` is not consistent to `Cache.size()`? 
Although I notice the javadoc of `Cache.size()` is:

```
  /**
   * Returns the **approximate** number of entries in this cache.
   */
```

I can just guess it's related to a concurrent environment.
And what does `Cache.cleanUp()` do exactly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Guava's cache is designed around lock amortization and the `cleanUp` method forces the cache to arrive at a consistent state. The `Map.size()` method is an approximation, but may count entries pending removal due to expiration or reference eviction. The visibility of the approximations in Guava's cache are rarely of much interest to an application, which tends to think of a cache as a transient data store. The different expectations of a cache from a Map led to the `asMap` method to allow the cache to be viewed as a map, but disfavor developers perceiving it that way.

The implementation details of the cache was covered in the StrangleLoop 2011 conference [slides](http://concurrentlinkedhashmap.googlecode.com/files/ConcurrentCachingAtGoogle.pdf). The [design document](http://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/wiki/Design) of `ConcurrentLinkedHashMap`, which Guava's cache was derived from, may also be of interest but describes a slightly different approach.

Answer (score 12):

Ben gave a good high-level response. The low-level response is:

`asMap()` views have the luxury of traversing each element in the cache, and thus can skip invalid entries which are pending cleanup. On the other hand, `size()` is expected to be a quick operation, and it would be silly to traverse the entire cache just to get a more accurate size estimate.

The [`CacheBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) javadocs go into more detail regarding the cleanup that needs to happen in various situations (such as `expireAfterWrite`, in your case).

Comment: Thank you, Charles! I went through the source code roughly, 'size()' just sums up count of Segment, as you mentioned- "silly to traverse the entire cache just to get a more accurate size estimate":) Highly sophisticated design!